# construction with an allocator must be possible if uses_allocator is true

Tags: c++, c++20, copy-constructor, allocator, c++pmr

I'm trying to create a pmr-allocated datastructure (compare code below). This however fails with an awful long error message and I can't quite track the root of it. At the end is a static_assert which says `construction with an allocator must be possible if uses_allocator is true`.

As far as I can tell, std::pmr::vector is trying to call the copy constructor of `profile` with an allocator which fails because 1) I didn't define a copy constructor and 2) the default copy constructor doesn't take into account allocator construction. **However**: Why is the copy constructor being selected in the first place? How did I urge std::pmr::vector to select the copy constructor over the default one?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQDMpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgABykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gHhyN5YANQmAW5sLCQAngD6xJgK65uYp9gmGgCCu/uHmCdnyBm%2BFQr3eX0%2BM2IXgcRxSxFQNHoYJMAHYrJ8jpijl4MkYjmJaKhRERiDcCFcUn9TgARI5AkAgFIsBKMzxXS7EFIIPDIG4EolMEmnNz0kAxK4EF4BN4BdHgj5Y2HwxGYCD84kkMkUv7qwUkf601FWFHU5ZgxWKkBY3Ukm5G/G0Qka4gnE3mrFG1HU5EY62OgW28mUo7ATAEPn%2B50QZauuUWrH3AgbBgOp160mnOMet2fd2Ym2aoM6yPpu2y5Fu8u5iEEKEwrwpdCCl65tF57G44CpgOF7UGukEdAMpkstK0dkkLk8iNpoVnUXiyWgqvyxUNpuStUlwN9gsummxr1m33xq2YuEIugPO1o7vO13ek%2BxxXtr0%2BhV%2B2e94Oh8N76OHk%2BiqJsmSqXvQCg3AAdL%2BM49sQ0aZq%2BOarlioojgyAButRzm4F4qq8YEqpBSGtt6K5gpC0IEHS8SYTyLZfG2T7rs2sKuOEwBlnKb4UdWHzhDRLBMOEiGtjxZEcKstCcAArLwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYdJPFsJxmAEPCkAQmhSasADWICyRo%2BicJICnGSpnC8AoIBWUZSlSaQcCwDAiAoKgLApFeZAUBAaABUFKAGEYZJQgwpl8HQkrEM5EAxPZMThE0VycAZYVsIIADyDDjvZWDCUY4juaQ%2BD3HU2HOVVmCqLUXiSvZgldPZtB4DExBZR4WD2bWeAsDlHlUAYwAKAAangmAAO4FZSikGfwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6hVboXD6IYxgaZY%2Bg9c5kCrKgKQ9A1AC0j1AjSpiWNYZgaEcj0AOoEj9BUKE5XQ4VkLgMO4nhtHooTzOUlR6IUmQCJMfjHcjPSDAjIzHTUdQCH0EzQ3keOgwTvSzNjwwJHjsxo3oMz9NTiy06sjwbFsei1pg2w8NJcl2VVqkcKoiQAGyPeLkhHAcp1HBAtZeHFMYQOpH0XUcuCEPquzHUcHjhfQ%2B56Vwyy8G5WjLKsCCYEwWAJNG1kcLZpCjZZpCKcpItOS5hnGasXm%2BesBApK15CUGFgXG5ErDbGLkvSyGyDIEcXBmFBZi8Jg%2BAkngQ7HWtwiiOI21F3taj2UdpDzX1KRjQLHDyZ79kiwVrVhzRCJHAnUsy3LeKK7Fpmq4b0fxLp%2Bnm/77nW6Q5kezJLu8O7Vle7wPu2H7lsmfPFlWUvARC97jkz1bjdZy3wunzvc/Ycl4OSEAA)

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <cstdio>

struct profile
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

    profile(allocator_type allocator = {})
        :   allocator_{ allocator }
    {}

    allocator_type get_allocator() {
        return allocator_;
    }

    allocator_type allocator_;
};

struct update
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

    update(allocator_type allocator = {})
        :   profiles_{ allocator }
    {    
    }

    allocator_type get_allocator() {
        return profiles_.get_allocator();
    }

    std::pmr::vector<profile> profiles_;
};

struct service
{
    update pending_;
};


int main()
{

}
```

Partial error (check above link to see whole traceback):

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/memory_resource:36:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/bits/memory_resource.h:41:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.0/../../../../include/c++/13.0.0/bits/uses_allocator_args.h:72:8: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'is_constructible_v<profile, const profile &, const std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<profile> &>': construction with an allocator must be possible if uses_allocator is true
              static_assert(is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args..., const _Alloc&>,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update(allocator_type allocator = {})
    :   profiles_{ allocator }
```

Converts `allocator` to `profile` and initializes `profiles_` with an initializer_list containing single element, which is getting copied.

Either change `{}` to `()` or make `profile` constructor explicit (you might want to provide separate non-explicit default constructor in this case)

Comment: Omg... I literally stared at this for hours, thank you! Could you elaborate why in the world this conversion sequence was chosen instead of the way more direct initialization with the allocator? And how is () different form {} in this case?

Comment: @glades in short, if you doing list-initialization (with {}) and object you are initializing has an initializer_list constructor, it is tried first and if there is any way it can work, it is chosen. Only if that constructor cannot work others are considered. Direct initialization (with () ) considers all constructors.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. That's helpful to say the least!